# AWS: Why do we have to specify 2 BGP ASN when configuring a DX Gateway?

Tags: aws-direct-connect

When creating a DX Gateway, we specify a BGP ASN. Another BGP ASN is required when specifying a VIF. Could someone explain why 2 BGP ASNs are required, and what purpose it solves?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know that BGP session is established between 2 peers, therefore BGP ASN is required for both the peers.

While creating the Direct Connect Gateway (DXGW), you mentions Amazon side BGP ASN, however while you are creating a VIF, you mentions on-premise (customer N/W) BGP ASN.

> While creating DXGW, it asks for Amazon side ASN
> (The Autonomous System Number for the new Direct Connect gateway.)

> While creating VIF, it asks for BGP ASN
> (The Border Gateway Protocol Autonomous System Number of your on-premises router for the new virtual interface.)

Hoping that this clears out your query.